# smartGWT: How to increase the TabPanel Header's Width

Tags: smartgwt

I have created a tabPanel in smartGWT,
Attached is the screenshot
I am trying to increase my tab headers width or to make my header name place vertically
so that the names "company information " and "relations"  can be visible in one line

I have use this widget

```
            http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_tabs_orientation
```

Any idea how can i increase my tab header's width or to make the headers title type vertically

thanks 
[image]

Comment: The setWidth works. If you want your title vertically you need to put html with br tag (T </br> i </br> etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For controlling the tabs' thickness(i.e. width) use:

```
tabset.setTabBarThickness(int tabBarThickness);
```

For showing the text with vertical orientation, you can use css to control the style of the text used as title for the tab. So something like the following shall suffice:

```
tab.setTitle("My Tab");
tab.setTitleStyle("tab-text");
```

And in the application's css:

```
.vtab-text, .vtab-textSelected, .vtab-textSelectedOver {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=90deg);  /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=90)"; /* IE8 */
    color: green;
 }
```